# How to give the option to the user to select a language during installing app whose installer has been prepared through visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I have developed an application using JAVA. And this product is targeted for the user of Korea. I have also prepared an installer using visual studio 2010. But the problem is I can not set multiple language as localization in visual studio 2010 installer project. I want to create an installer so that user can select language during installation. How can I provide this option? any idea?

Please note that, the language is only for the installer program. The app will not affected by this.

Comment: As currently asked, it is a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: OK. Actually I want to create an installer that will facilitate an user to select language when the installer is run. And the installer programs language will be changed according to user's requirement

Comment: Suppose there will be two option English and Korean. An user can select any of these of language.

Comment: @frasnian is it clear now? If you want I can chat with you :)

Comment: From what I know there is no way to create a multilingual VS setup project which at install time will let the user to choose the install language. I'm not sure if this is a feasible choice for you, but as an alternative solution you can try to use a paid installer tool like InstallShield or Advanced Installer.

Comment: @herman.smn can you please right your comment as an answer? So that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know there is no way to create a multilingual VS setup project which at install time will let the user to choose the install language. I'm not sure if this is a feasible choice for you, but as an alternative solution you can try to use a paid installer tool like InstallShield or Advanced Installer.